# Checking actor type in projectile ProcessTouch

Tags: udk

I'm trying to teleport a pawn when it's struck by a projectile (or damaged by any weapon in my game) .

Right now, I'm trying to just call `Pawn.SetLocation` in the projectile's ProcessTouch. That's a problem because `ProcessTouch` will hit any actor, not just a pawn. Additionally, any attempts to check the `ProcessTouch`'s "Actor Other" throw errors.

I've tried a bunch of solutions (including making an event `TakeDamage` in the `Pawn` controller class) but to no avail.

```
simulated function ProcessTouch(Actor Other, Vector HitLocation, Vector HitNormal)
{
    if (Other != Instigator)
    {
        //This is where the Other.TakeDamage goes if we are using a traditional gun.
        if (Other == Pawn);
        {
             Other.SetLocation(0,0,0);
        }
    }
    Destroy;
}
```

This code complains that `Pawn` is a bad expression. How else should I check actor type here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss to cast your pawn as :

```
if( myDesiredClass(Other) != none)
```

Check it and give me feedback if you face any new problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could either do it by checking the class

Other.class == class'Pawn'

or by casting and checking it whether it's None or not

Pawn(Other) != None